# How to update data using particular ID in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update some data in SQLite. This is the code to edit the data:

```
db.open();
c = db.getData();
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Log.v("_______BACK PRESSED", "______UUID___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid")));
        Log.v("_______pos", "______UUID___________"+pos);
        String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ="+ edittext.getText().toString() +"  WHERE uuid = "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid")) ;

        db.select(strSQL);
        Log.v("_______BACK PRESSED", "______UUID___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid")));
        Log.v("_______BACK PRESSED", "______devicename___________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));

        Log.v("___________text", "_______________"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("devicename")));
        Log.v("___________edittext", "_______________"+edittext.getText().toString());
        Log.v("_____ADDRESS______edittext", "_______________"+pos);
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("Dname", edittext.getText().toString());
        Log.v("_____edittext in intent________", "__________"+edittext.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("Daddress",pos);
        Log.v("_____edittext in intent________", "__________"+pos);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}

db.close();
```

and in database adapter, I did as following for executing the query. But it is not updating the data.

```
public Cursor select(String query) throws SQLException {
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Comment: Enclose your strings with 'single quote' marks

Comment: Some reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow, http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your string literals are not properly `''` quoted for SQL. However, the best option is to use `?` placeholder and bind arguments.
2. Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for updates. `rawQuery()` alone won't run the SQL; `execSQL()` will.

Example:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename = ? WHERE uuid = ?",
    new String[] {
        edittext.getText().toString(),
        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))
    });
```

Comment: hi, in adapter how to add execSQL()

Comment: The same way as you have the `rawQuery()` there, e.g. passing the string parameters as arguments.

Comment: see this like this only public void select(String query) throws SQLException {
          db.execSQL(query, null);
     }

Comment: i had other issues also please help me. i will send the full project so please help me. in those issues.how to send full project.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **renaming** its simple updating

and an update query will do this as you are doing so

just update your query with this

```
String strSQL = "UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='"+ edittext.getText().toString() +"'  WHERE uuid = '"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"))+"'" ;
```

Comment: hi,i got this error while doing this.03-21 11:43:17.198: E/MessageQueue-JNI(5836): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":1A": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='gxyxyzuc'  WHERE uuid = 00:1A:5B:00:15:10

Comment: 03-21 11:43:17.198: E/MessageQueue-JNI(5836): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ":1A": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE DeviceDetails SET devicename ='gxyxyzuc'  WHERE uuid = 00:1A:5B:00:15:10

Comment: I think you missed the enclosing `'` for UUID.

Comment: @user254633 You are also missing `'` in uuid just see the updated query from my answer

Comment: s it executed but it was not rename to oldname why

Comment: so there is no uuid of your input `'00:1A:5B:00:15:10'`

Comment: it is there first i insert then i am updating

Comment: say how to send complete project i will send to u.please help me

Comment: hi today is my deadline if not i will lost job.so please help me na say how to send complete project i had issues .

Comment: it was not replacing also please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.update` to update rows in your database not `.rawQuery`

```
String value = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"));
String[] whereVars = new String[]{value};
String where = "uuid = ?"

ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put("devicename", edittext.getText().toString());

db.update("DeviceDetails", args, where, whereVars);
```

I'll also let you know that the performance for your above code, updates in a loop, will be crap.. so you should do all updates in a single transaction:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            updateDeviceByUuid(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("uuid"),  
                               edittext.getText().toString());
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

and

```
public int updateDeviceByUuid(String uuid, String deviceName){
    String[] whereVars = new String[]{uuid};
    String where = "uuid = ?"

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("devicename", deviceName);

    return db.update("DeviceDetails", args, where, whereVars);
}
```